# Tablix (Table) in RDLC report should grow upward when number of rows added/increase

Tags: asp.net-core, reporting, rdlc, ssrs-tablix

I want to develop an RDLC report, where a tablix element will grow in upward direction i.e. when more rows are added, the table will grow upwards (as opposed to downwards).

Basically, as per our design, we need to add the table close the footer of the page, mostly with 1 or 2 rows of data. If the table gets more than 1-2 rows, it should grow upwards.

[image]

How can I achieve this (i.e. rows highlighted with red arrow should grow up)?

Comment: Coulld you show your codes related?

Comment: @RuikaiFeng thr is no code, its a RDLC report, so I need to know how to achieve this using RDLC tools

Comment: Oh,Sorry,the issue has asp.net core tag,I misunderstood you want to show the report in Pages